# Any Xampp Like For Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm still new to ruby and i'm in the process to learn it, i'm actually using Xampp for php on windows, but i'm stuck at finding a complete package to install a RoR server just like Xampp without any manual work.

Is there any tool out there?

Comment: I don't think there is any tool available like xampp for ROR. You need to install ruby, rubygems, rails separately.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/)

Answer (score 1):

One of your choices is to use built in mongrel/webrick server which comes with each rails app. Just type `$ rails s` at the console and you're good to go. Otherwise I don't think it's particularly useful to deploy an app each time you change something.